# push_back method is not working with my vector of classes, "No instance of overloaded function."

Tags: class, vector, methods, arguments, overloading

I am passing a vector of classes to a function and attempting to use the push_back method on the formal parameters. I get a "No instance of overloaded function".

[image: 1]

I am trying to compare a class instance to an element of the vector. If there is a match, delete the element that i contains.
i understand that push_back is not the method I need but I am confused as to why it is not recognizing the methods of vector.

Answer (score 0):

**push_back()** method accept only vector type. Passing [i] is an error because it refers nothing. You should be pass the movie at index i such this:

```
movie.push_back(movie[i]);
```

But I think your function wants to remove the movie object from the vector.
You should use **erase()** method to remove i index element

So if the name of the movie passed in the function is equal to the name of movie found in the vector you delete it.

```
movie.erase(movie.begin() + i);
```

**begin()** method is used to point the first element of the vector then you sum the i value to point the desired element to delete

Watch the vector class reference for more:
https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
I hope my answer solves your problem.

Comment: You use push_back() to add an element to the last element of the vector

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I am not getting any errors when using the code snippet, but my for loop that contains the snippet is not being executed. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Finally got it working! Your code worked like a charm! Thanks again.